# How do I uninstall a folder of node modules that's been installed in the wrong directory (Mac)?

Tags: node.js, npm, stylelint

I have accidentally installed 409 node modules in a project directory, while trying to install the 'stylelint' module.

I'm unfamiliar with this and thought it was going into a 'global' place (wherever that is) but instead it's installed it and 408 other modules into a "node_modules" folder, along with "package-lock.json" in a low level project directory.

I did this by running the following command in the random project directory by mistake:
`sudo npm install stylelint --save-dev`

And then in an attempt to remove it:
`sudo npm uninstall stylelint'

It says it has removed 1 package of the 409. It also gave a bunch of warnings each time about missing descriptions/readmes.

I just want to completely undo what I did - uninstall all these modules, remove all the new files etc. Please could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just remove the `npm_modules` directory:

```
$ rm -rf my_project/npm_modules
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this the same as uninstalling them all?

Comment: @user231207 Installing a node module simply places it in a directory under `node_modules` (and possibly runs some init script that may, e.g., compile native components). Deleting them is sort of a forceful way of removing them.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! Do I run "rm -rf node_modules" and then "rm -rf package-lock.json" in the folder I'm in and that will delete everything?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!